# How can I get the CheckBoxList selected values, what I have doesn't seem to work C#.NET/VisualWebPart

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, htmltextwriter

I am creating a CheckBoxList in a class file and am using an HTMLTextWriter to render the control.

I'm using the following code to store the selected values in a string:

```
string YrStr = "";
for (int i = 0; i < YrChkBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (YrChkBox.Items[i].Selected)
    {
        YrStr += YrChkBox.Items[i].Value + ";"; 
    }
}
```

I stepped through the code and it doesn't seem to hit the inside of the if statement & the selected value attribute is false every time ... Anyone have an idea of how I can address this?

I populate it using the following:

```
 YrChkBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "Item1"));
```

Comment: this code should work.. what event do you have this code placed under also do you actually YrChkBox.Items.Count have a value..??

Comment: OnClick; the answer to the if statement always seems to be false. This is in a Class file though, would PostBacks have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In your ASPX page you've got the list like this:

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="YrChkBox" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="YrChkBox_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
    <asp:Button ID="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
```

In your code behind aspx.cs page, you have this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // Populate the CheckBoxList items only when it's not a postback.
            YrChkBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 1", "Item1"));
            YrChkBox.Items.Add(new ListItem("Item 2", "Item2"));
        }
    }

    protected void YrChkBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the list to store.
        List<String> YrStrList = new List<string>();
        // Loop through each item.
        foreach (ListItem item in YrChkBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                // If the item is selected, add the value to the list.
                YrStrList.Add(item.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                // Item is not selected, do something else.
            }
        }
        // Join the string together using the ; delimiter.
        String YrStr = String.Join(";", YrStrList.ToArray());

        // Write to the page the value.
        Response.Write(String.Concat("Selected Items: ", YrStr));
    }
```

Ensure you use the `if (!IsPostBack) { }` condition because if you load it every page refresh, it's actually destroying the data.

Comment: I do not have it in the mark up at all. I have it in a text writer. Give me a second I'll paste my code for that part.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying, add the selected values to a list as they get selected... I'll try that, I'm worried about reloading the page everytime a user selects a checkbox though

Comment: You can remove the AutoPostBack="True" part from the ASPX page, and it should behave the same way on a post back event from another event such as a button press.  That was just for an example.

Comment: I can't seem to add a Server-Side control in Code-behind and add render it through HTMLTextWriter... any ideas on how I can do this. I really need to be able to retrieve the selected values of the checkbox list, thank you for your help +1

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in YrChkBox.Items)
{
    if (listItem.Selected)
    { 
       //do some work 
    }
    else 
    { 
      //do something else 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Kraze Exactly what I have right now.. except I have it in a for loop, I tried it with your syntax and yes it is in fact the same thing but I like your syntax more so I'll keep it lol +1

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying, yeah you're right I wasn't doing that. I really wish that helped though T_T i'm having the same issue.. I think it is because my button is not serverside

Answer (score 3):

### check boxlist selected values with seperator

```
 string items = string.Empty;
        foreach (ListItem i in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (i.Selected == true)
            {
                items += i.Text + ",";
            }
        }
        Response.Write("selected items"+ items);
```

Answer (score 3):

An elegant way to implement this would be to make an extension method, like this:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<string> GetSelectedItems(this CheckBoxList cbl)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        foreach (ListItem item in cbl.Items)
            if (item.Selected)
                result.Add(item.Value);

        return result;
    }
}
```

I can then use something like this to compose a string will all values separated by ';':

```
string.Join(";", cbl.GetSelectedItems());
```

Answer (score 0):

// Page.aspx //

```
// To count checklist item

  int a = ChkMonth.Items.Count;
        int count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            if (ChkMonth.Items[i].Selected == true)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
```

//  Page.aspx.cs  //

```
  // To access checkbox list item's value //
   string YrStrList = "";
        foreach (ListItem listItem in ChkMonth.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Selected)
            {
                YrStrList = YrStrList + "'" + listItem.Value + "'" + ",";
            }

        }

        sMonthStr = YrStrList.ToString();
```

Answer (score -1):

**// aspx.cs**

**// Load CheckBoxList selected items into ListBox**

```
    int status = 1;
    foreach (ListItem  s in chklstStates.Items  )
    {
        if (s.Selected == true)
        {
            if (ListBox1.Items.Count == 0)
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add(s.Text);

            }
            else
            {
                foreach (ListItem list in ListBox1.Items)
                {
                    if (list.Text == s.Text)
                    {
                        status = status * 0;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = status * 1;
                    }
                }
                if (status == 0)
                { }
               else
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(s.Text);
                }
                status = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```