# CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged does not get fired

Tags: asp.net

I have checkboxlist. User is able to check multiple checkboxes.I want to fetch
checkboxe's text.So I wrote like this.But my event(CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged) does not get fire.I already made checkboxlist's autopostback = "true".

```
string str = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
{
str = CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Text;
str = str +',';
}
}
str = str.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: How did you figure out whether event is getting fired or not? Have you tried to debug?

Comment: Function fired.But I did not write anything inside it, just assign.When I used break point,I got it.Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523263/how-can-i-get-the-checkboxlist-selected-values-what-i-have-doesnt-seem-to-work