# how to get checked or unchecked in checkbox list

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, checkbox, checkboxlist, selectedindexchanged

Check box list how to get boolean value of the check box list likewise 
if checked return true if unchecked return false. i tried using for in selected it return true for all the check box.return boolean value based on checked and unchecked

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="ChkPermission" runat="server" 
                onselectedindexchanged="ChkPermission_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                style="text-align: left">
                        <asp:ListItem>Access</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Add</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Edit</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Delete</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Print</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Export</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c

Comment: clear question there no value for the list item.like we use in checkbox.checked condition i need similarly like that in checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

I have edited this and posted answer in C# to suit @maccettura. I found this bit of code from here [How can I get the CheckBoxList selected values, what I have doesn't seem to work C#.NET/VisualWebPart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523263/how-can-i-get-the-checkboxlist-selected-values-what-i-have-doesnt-seem-to-work). There are a few different kind of examples on this link if this code below doesn't work for you.

```
 protected void YrChkBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (ListItem listItem in YrChkBox.Items)
{
if (listItem.Selected)
{ 
   //do some work 
}
else 
{ 
  //do something else 
}
}}
```

Comment: OP has tagged C# 4.0, please provide answers in C#