# If ELSE condition not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I have a Multiple Select `DROPDOWNLIST` to select items.  See the `Dropdownlist` below

[![dropdownlist][1]][1]

What I am doing is, I am selecting `2` items from the list. One of `PROCESSED` and another of `PENDING`

So what's happening wrong here is, when the condition is `PROCESSED` it works properly and goes in `IF` condition but second time it is `PENDING` but still it goes in the `IF` condition.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString()))
{
    using (SqlCommand sqcmd = new SqlCommand("select  month(a.dt_of_leave)month, year(a.dt_of_leave)year   " +
        "from emp_mst a where month(a.dt_of_leave) >= month(getdate())-1  and   " +
        "year(a.dt_of_leave)= case when  month(getdate())=1   " +
        "then year(getdate())-1 else year(getdate()) end  " +
        "and emp_card_no IN (" + str_emp_sel + ") order by emp_name", conn))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter damonthyear = new SqlDataAdapter(sqcmd);
        damonthyear.Fill(dtspmonthyear);

        for (i = 0; i < dtspmonthyear.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cmbEmp_Name.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("PROCESSED") == true)
            {
                //CF.ExecuteQuerry("exec Emp_Resign_Allocate_Leave '" + str_emp_sel + "','" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["month"].ToString() + "', '" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["year"].ToString() + "'");
            }
            else
            {
                // not going in else for `PENDING`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the markup:

```
<asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="cmbEmp_Name" AddJQueryReference="true" Width="60%" runat="server"
                            DataTextField="Employee Name" DataValueField="User_ID" UseSelectAllNode="false">
                            <Style DropDownBoxBoxWidth="500px" DropDownBoxBoxHeight="45%" SelectBoxWidth="55%" />
                        </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

Comment: You can bet that `if()` ain't broken, so it must be your code. Set breakpoints, step through your code and inspect your variables. Did you notice that you're looking at `cmbEmp_Name.` **`SelectedItem`**, so the same item every iteration?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: @CodeCaster: tried debugging and checked, it's going in `IF` condition always.

Comment: what is the value of "cmbEmp_Name.SelectedItem.Text" ?

Comment: I bet that cmbEmp_Name.SelectedItem is always returning the same selected item (first one from all selected items).. Shouldn't you iterate through the selected items ?

Comment: @PranavPatel: the value is `GAURAV JHUNJHUNWALA-2222(March - 2016) PROCESSED`

Comment: yes then is returns true,

Comment: @PonasJustas: yes second time also its taking the first one. So what to do for this

Comment: If you're selecting two items won't it return true since you're only checking if it contains Pending which is true?

Comment: cmbEmp_Name.SelectedItem.Text.Contains("PROCESSED") == true so your selected value "GAURAV JHUNJHUNWALA-2222(March - 2016) PROCESSED" contains word "PROCESSED" so it returns true

Comment: @PranavPatel: so how to make it check depending upon `PROCESSED` and `PENDING`

Comment: try something similar to
foreach (var item in cmbEmp_Name.SelectedItems)
{
    if (item.Text.Contains("PROCESSED") == true)
                    {
                        //CF.ExecuteQuerry("exec Emp_Resign_Allocate_Leave '" + str_emp_sel + "','" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["month"].ToString() + "', '" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["year"].ToString() + "'");
                    }
                    else
                    {
             // not going in else for `PENDING`
                    }
}

Comment: Also a bit redundant is saying "== true" as Contains returns a bool. Otherwise I'd try something as recomended by @Ponas

Comment: @PonasJustas: the code is too messy to read and copy. kindly put it as an answer

Comment: @coder, what if you select value which contains "PENDING" ?

Comment: @PranavPatel: when I select as `PENDING` I get text as `NEHA ARUN KHANNA-2145(March - 2016) PENDING`

Comment: What kind of control is this?

Comment: There is no such control in ASP.NET. If you donwloaded some control from the web, read its documentation to perform the task you want to do (_"Iterate over selected items"_?).

Comment: @CodeCaster: I guess it is almost an ASP.NET control. I have downloaded its dll and I am using very much easily fine with it. I m just stucked in `iteration` part. let me know how to move further with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something similar to:

```
for (i = 0; i < dtspmonthyear.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    foreach (var item in cmbEmp_Name.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            if (item.Text.Contains("PROCESSED"))
            {
                //CF.ExecuteQuerry("exec Emp_Resign_Allocate_Leave '" + str_emp_sel + "','" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["month"].ToString() + "', '" + dtspmonthyear.Rows[0]["year"].ToString() + "'");
            }
            else
            {
                // not going in else for `PENDING`
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error as `dropdowncheckboxes does not contain a definition Selecteditems` at `SelectedItems`

Comment: Can you do a foreach on SelectedItem?

Comment: What is the object type of cmbEmp_Name ?

Comment: @PonasJustas: it is input type as  `checkbox` in view source

Comment: Error, as `System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.listitemcollection` does not contain a definition for Where .....

Comment: @coder add a Using System.Linq; . Where(x => x.Selected) just is a simplier way of saying if (item.Selected). You dont have to use the linq method and just have an if statement inside the foreach to check if item.Selected equals true

Comment: Superb, that's working now. I added it like this `foreach (var item in cmbEmp_Name.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Where(x => x.Selected))`

Comment: Glad to hear you found a way to your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently downloaded [some control from the web](https://dropdowncheckboxes.codeplex.com/). Its documentation states:

> DropDownCheckBoxes is an ASP.NET server control directly inheriting from standard ASP.NET CheckBoxList control.

Cool, so we can just search the web for what we want to do: *"ASP.NET CheckBoxList get selected items"*, which yields Q&As like [How can I get the CheckBoxList selected values, what I have doesn't seem to work C#.NET/VisualWebPart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523263/how-can-i-get-the-checkboxlist-selected-values-what-i-have-doesnt-seem-to-work), [How to get values of selected items in CheckBoxList with foreach in ASP.NET C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924147/how-to-get-values-of-selected-items-in-checkboxlist-with-foreach-in-asp-net-c) and so on:

```
foreach (ListItem item in dropDownCheckBoxList.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        // Do what you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: do I need to add this as `item.Selected == "PROCESSED")` to check for processed one ?? or as it is?

Comment: No, the `ListItem.Selected` property indicates that the `ListItem` instance is selected, as simple as that. If you want to get its text, you use `item.Text`.

Comment: So, If I select one from `PENDING` also then also it will go as in `IF` condition..

Comment: No, you need to stop copy-pasting code and try to understand what you read and paste. This code I provided gives you the items that were selected. I don't know what your code is supposed to do, but this should help you further with getting the items that were selected. It might be very possible that within this `if()` shown here, you need to write more code, but I don't know what your code is supposed to do and was frankly hoping you could figure it out from there.

Comment: I was already getting the `selecteditem` the one which u provided.my main concern was I wan not able to get the items for `processed` and `pending` i tried with ur code like this also `item.Selected.ToString() == "PROCESSED"` but stil for processed it is going in `else` part...

Comment: No, you do **not** need to access `SelectedItem`, because that only returns one item while you can select multiple. I don't know why you did `item.Selected.ToString()`, because that is only going to yield "True" or "False" and never "PROCESSED". You need, inside `if (item.Selected) { ... }`, to inspect `item.Text`. Again, **stop copy-pasting and start debugging**. Set breakpoints, inspect your variables.

Comment: I got the answer which I was expecting from you. The thing which u answered was already done by me. IF you go through my question u will get what I exactly wanted and where I was stucked. Upvote +1 for your documentation and logic part.

Comment: Ok, happy to help.