# How do I get the sum of radioButtons?

Tags: c#, string, sum, radio-button

I have 16 Radio Button and I am trying to add the value of 4 radio button in each of 4 cases how I can?
How do I get the sum of the sixteen radioButton?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string ChosenMovie = "";

    if (radioButton1.Checked)
    {
        //label2.Text = "100";
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }        
    if (radioButton2.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton3.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton4.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton5.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton6.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton7.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton8.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton9.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton10.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton11.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton12.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton13.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "100" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton14.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "60" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton15.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "30" + "\r\n";
    }
    if (radioButton16.Checked)
    {
        ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + "0" + "\r\n";     
        MessageBox.Show(ChosenMovie);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to cast 'em all to int?

Comment: You need to be clearer about what output you want and how and where you're using it.

Comment: A string "100" is not an integer 100 (note the quotes). The plus operator works differently if it is applied to a string or to a number. Now try to apply this concept to your code.

Comment: Instead of misusing the text you can store any value in the Tag of the RBs.

Comment: why aren't you used checkboxlist?

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ how it used  ??? plz tell me

Comment: @Steve i am at intial level in c# so plz guide me more

Comment: like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9523471/7036750 or http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/bind-the-checkbox-list-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ it is very tough for me because i am at started level in c#

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make sure that `ChosenMovie` is an `int` type.

If the number you want to add to `ChosenMovie` comes from a string like `label2.Text` that you wrote on a commented line, then you can use [`Convert.ToInt32()` or `int.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx):

```cs
...

if (radioButton1.Checked)
{
    //label2.Text = "100";

    // by Convert.ToInt32()
    ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text);

    // or, by int.TryParse()
    ChosenMovie = ChosenMovie + int.TryParse(label2.Text);
}
```